# Application pool deleted after iis reset

Tags: c#, iis

I'm write installer for my web site. Installer creating application pool, virtual directory and assign virtual directory to application pool using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525598.aspx) instruction. All work, but... If i reset IIS immediately after install my program, my application pool deleted, but if i open if open my web site in web browser and then reset IIS, application pool not deleted.
Why this happens?

I'm using IIS 6.0 (windows server 2003), C# 3.0 and windows installer

P.S. sorry for my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slight delay in application pool registration.  If you open your website it forces that operation to complete.  If you don't, and you reset before it completes, then it's gone.

Are you calling `iisreset /nowait`?  This will cause it to abandon that registration, calling just `iisreset` should let it finish.

Try `iisreset /noforce` to be safe with this, it'll wait until IIS finishes, and if it times out waiting, won't forcefully kill anything.  If it takes a long time, give it a timeout that's higher, the default is 60 seconds.  You can do this via:  `iisreset /noforce /timeout:300` to give it 5 minutes of slack.

Comment: I reset using Computer management window, in context menu I choose All Tasks -> Restart IIS.

>>There is a slight delay in application pool registration
how many time?

Comment: I'd been going crazy with this issue, this helped a ton!